# PDO query run only first time

Tags: php, html, pdo

I'm trying to get info from database but the query runs only for the first row!
I have tried many things but it didn't work; I don't know why.
The get method is on table that is filled by the database

The issue is in the first query `'SELECT CouID FROM CoursesC WHERE StuID = :ID '`
if I change the query to `'SELECT CouID FROM CoursesC'` it works fine!

I'm presenting the data into a `<select>` inside a modal

**FORM CODE**

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="GET" id="contact">

<table  id="studenttable">

  <tr>
  <th></th>
  <th>Student ID</th>
  <th>Student Name</th>
  <th>Student Passed Credits</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
  <?php

    require('check.php');
$query = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM student WHERE AdvID=:id' );
$query->bindParam(":id",$_SESSION['userid']);
$query->execute();
$row = $query->fetch();

while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
 ?>
  <tr>
  <td> <input type ="checkbox" name="checked[]" value="<?php echo $row['StuId'];?>"> </td>
  <td><?php echo $row['StuId']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['Name']; ?></td>
  <td> </td>
  <td> 

  <button  type="submit" name="submit" value="<?php echo $row['StuId'];?>" class="btn icon-btn btn-info" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>More Information</button>
  </td>
  </tr>    
<?php
}
      do {
    while ($query->fetch())
        ;
    if (!$query->nextRowset())
        break;
} while (true);
    $conn=null;
    $query->closeCursor();
?> 

</table>

</form>




<?php
if (isset($_GET['submit'])){
    global $CC;
    $count=1;
    global $data;
    $T=$_GET['submit'];
?>
<script>
    $('#CC').html("");
    $('#CC1').html("");
</script>
<?php
    require('check.php');
    $q= $conn->prepare('SELECT CouID FROM CoursesC WHERE StuID = :ID ');
    $q->bindValue(':ID', $_GET['submit'] );
    $q->execute();
    $data = $q->fetch();
    while($data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $CC=$data['CouID'];
?>
<script>
    $('#CC').append("<option><? echo $count++; echo "- "; echo $CC;?></option>");
</script>
<?php
    }
    $q->closeCursor();
    $A=$CC;
    /*echo "<script> alert('<?php $T ?>')";*/

    $q1= $conn->prepare('SELECT CouID FROM Courses');
    $q1->execute();
    $data1 = $q1->fetch();
    while($data1 = $q1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        if($CC!=$data1['CouID']){
?>
<script>
    $('#CC1').append("<option><? echo $count++; echo "- "; echo $data1['CouID'];?></option>");
</script>
<?php
        }
    }
    $q1->closeCursor();
?>
<script>
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
</script>
<?
}
?>
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['submit'])){
        global $CC;
        $count=1;
        global $data;
        $T=$_GET['submit'];
?>
<script>
     $('#CC').html("");
     $('#CC1').html("");
</script>
<?php
        require('check.php');
        $q= $conn->prepare('SELECT CouID FROM CoursesC WHERE StuID = :ID ');
        $q->bindValue(':ID', $_GET['submit'] );
        $q->execute();
        $data = $q->fetch();
        while($data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $CC=$data['CouID'];
?>
<script>
     $('#CC').append("<option><? echo $count++; echo "- "; echo $CC;?></option>");
</script>
<?php
        }
        $q->closeCursor();
        $A=$CC;
        /*echo "<script> alert('<?php $T ?>')";*/

        $q1= $conn->prepare('SELECT CouID FROM Courses');
        $q1->bindParam(":id", $_GET['submit']);
        $q1->execute();
        $data1 = $q1->fetch();
        while($data1 = $q1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            if($CC!=$data1['CouID']){
?>
<script>
     $('#CC1').append("<option><? echo $count++; echo "- "; echo $data1['CouID'];?></option>");
</script>
<?php
            }
        }
        $q1->closeCursor();
?>
<script>
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
</script>
<?
    }
?>
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['submit'])){
      global $CC;
        $count=1;
        global $data;
        $T=$_GET['submit'];
    ?>
    <script>
     $('#CC').html("");
     $('#CC1').html("");
    </script>
    <?php
    require('check.php');
    $q= $conn->prepare('SELECT CouID FROM CoursesC WHERE StuID = :ID ');
    $q->bindValue(':ID', $_GET['submit'] );
    $q->execute();
    $data = $q->fetch();
    while($data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $CC=$data['CouID'];
?>
<script>
     $('#CC').append("<option><? echo $count++; echo "- "; echo $CC;?></option>");
</script>
<?php
    }
    $q->closeCursor();
    $A=$CC;
    /*echo "<script> alert('<?php $T ?>')";*/

    $q1= $conn->prepare('SELECT CouID FROM Courses');
    $q1->bindParam(":id", $_GET['submit']);
    $q1->execute();
    $data1 = $q1->fetch();
    while($data1 = $q1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        if($CC!=$data1['CouID']){
?>
<script>
     $('#CC1').append("<option><? echo $count++; echo "- "; echo $data1['CouID'];?></option>");
</script>
<?php
        }
    }
    $q1->closeCursor();
?>
<script>
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
</script>
<?
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi your question is very broad, when you say the "query", you need to specific what query, in your code there are a lot of queries. If you are very specific will be more easy help you.

Comment: @PabloCesarCordovaMorales sorry i had update my comment its the first query and i think the problem in  $q->bindValue because when i remove it its work but i need it to get value by user

Comment: `:ID` and `:id` are two different animals but you're not doing anything with `$q1= $conn->prepare('SELECT CouID FROM Courses');
    $q1->bindParam(":id", $_GET['submit']);` as in no binds and don't know why you're using a submit as a reference.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I just copy the code and i didn't delete it :)

Comment: Try to run the query alone, I would guess theres only one record which matches the ID you provide, so it's working fine?

Comment: @PauloHenrique i already get the IDs from the database so idont think this is the problem
(there is another query before these queries)

Comment: `$q->bindValue(':ID', $_GET['submit'] );` Look very odd to me. But as we cannot see the form you are using WHO KNOWS

Comment: Yes... maybe the problem isn't the query, but the form which is sending the data... if you post the values {$_GET['submit']} are sending, this would clarify to us...

Comment: @RiggsFolly i have Edit the code with Form

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
$q= $conn->prepare('SELECT CouID FROM CoursesC WHERE StuID = :ID ');
$q->bindValue(':ID', $_GET['submit'] );
```

to

```
$q= $conn->prepare('SELECT CouID FROM CoursesC WHERE StuID IN( :ID ) ');
$q->bindValue(':ID', implode(",",$_GET['checked']) );
```

Your form is returning an array of IDs, not just one, so you must use 'IN' instead of '='.

Also, don't use `<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>`. Use the name of page, in case you're deploying this outside of your project!

Comment: i think you have confused didn't use "checked" its for check box i use submit button to send its value THNX

Comment: Yes, and it's incorrect. The $_GET variable will return an array of elements of your form already. I am assuming you pretend to retrieve the checked ID, so there's another array inside called "checked" which is the name you gave for these elements. Each element inside checked array is an ID value. Implode function convert them to a string readable in you SQL statement.

Comment: Sorry, I think I understood the logic here... If the user clicks the button, then ONE user ID is sent, correct? So I don't get why your query would return a list then if you are filtering one user ID...

Comment: what iam doing here is an advisor page when the advisor click on the button in the student row a modal must appear with a list of completed courses and another list with non completed courses and the checked box is useless i will remove it :)